# Reference request: Integral rigid spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, nonarchimedian-analysis, rigid-analytic-spaces

Is there a notion of integral rigid spaces which mirrors the theory of integral schemes? For instance, let $B$ be an integral affinoid algebra over a non-Archimedean field $k$. Then are the affinoid algebras corresponding to affinoid open subsets of $Sp(B)$ integral? More generally, what is a suitable notion of a integral rigid analytic space?

Particularly interesting is to know whether, the rational subsets of $Sp(B)$ are integral.
Since the rational open subsets are the analogues of the principle open subsets of an affine scheme, I would like to know if anybody knows any reference where the notion of integral rigid spaces have been discussed. Standard references don't seem to contain anything about it.

Comment: Honestly, although I have gone through BGR and Bosch's notes, I cannot immediately recall anything along these lines. Could please maybe give some context to the question (as in, is this just curiosity, or is it important to understand something else)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The context for which I require the answer is to understand the inverse images of neighborhoods of points w.r.t. a finite map $\pi:Sp(B) \rightarrow Sp(A)$, where $f:A \hookrightarrow B$ is an inclusion. I wanted to know whether given Y is integral, there exists a n.b.d. around each point that pulls back to an integral n.b.d. This is immediate when it is a map of Spec's since the principle open set $Spec(A_t)$ pulls back to $Spec(B_{f(t)})$, both of which will be integral if $A,B$ are integral. But what about rational subdomains in $Sp(A)$ and their pull backs?

Comment: Is $Y=\operatorname{Sp}(A)$ or $\operatorname{Sp}(B)$?

Comment: I meant $Y$ to be $Sp(A)$ but I would like both spaces to be integral.

Comment: One particular case, which I tried working out(and it would be great if someone can validate it) is when the spectral norm on $B$ is multiplicative. For if, $\{f_0,....,f_n\} \subset B$ generate the unit ideal and $B \rightarrow C$ is the rational subdomain associated to it, then if we can find an dense subring which is an integral domain we're done(this is basically due to the multiplicativity hypothesis). I claim the dense subring is $B_{f_0}$, which is integral if $B$ is.

Comment: The claim I think follows immediately once we observe that $B[T_0,...,T_n]/(f_i-T_i f_0)_i \simeq B_{f_0}$ is indeed dense inside $C$, which is clear from the definition of the rational subdomain $C$ corresponding to $(f_0,...,f_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are unlikely to find this notion appearing in the literature is that it is not nearly as well-behaved as it is in the algebraic situation.

Let us take our base definition of an *integral* finite type $k$-scheme (for some field $k$) as one which is reduced (i.e. the local rings are reduced) and irreducible. The reducedness condition is (roughly) OK in the rigid setting, but irreducibility is much, much more delicate.

**Example:** The closed disk $\{|x|\leqslant 1\}$ is not topologically irreducible. Indeed, this is equivalent to all non-empty open subsets being dense, but if $a$ is such that $|a|=1$, then $\{|x-a|<1\}$ and $\{|x|<1\}$ are disjoint open subsets. $\blacksquare$

Since any definition of 'irreducible' should contain the closed disk, we see that naive irreducibility is not a good notion. What is used instead is Zariski irreducibility -- a rigid space $X$ is *Zariski irreducible* if it cannot be written as a union of two disjoint Zariski closed subsets. This is then satisfied if $X$ is the closed unit disk.

The problem is that Zariski irreducibility is not preserved under passage to arbitrary possibly non-Zariski (e.g., affinoid) opens, and so doesn't behave as you would expect. The reason for this is that the topology of rigid spaces is much richer.

**Example:** Let $X=\mathrm{Spa}(\mathbb{Q}_p[x,y](y^2-x^3-x^2))$. Then, $X$ is irreducible, essentially because $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}_p[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2))$ is. That said, consider the affinoid open $\{|x|\leqslant \tfrac{1}{2}\}$. Then, one can see that
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\sum_{n\geqslant 1}{{\tfrac{1}{2}}\choose{n}}x^n,$$
converges $p$-adically on this affinoid, and thus $y^2-x^3-x^2$ is no longer Zariski irreducible. $\blacksquare$

Compare this with the notion of [(geometrically) unibranch](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BQ2) from scheme theory, where the above also gives a non-example. The non-unibranchness is detected by so-called 'analytic branches', which are something like irreducible components which appear 'analytically locally'. That is what is happening in the previous example, except in the analytic world 'analytically locally' is not a drastic operation, but the basic one!

Given this, a hint towards at least one good integral-like notion for rigid spaces is that of *normal* rigid spaces (compare with [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BQ3)). In particular, if $X$ is a normal rigid space, and $U\subseteq X$ is a connected affinoid open, then $\mathcal{O}(U)$ is an integral domain (cf.[1, Corollary 3.3.21]).

**References:**

[1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BQ2) Berkovich, V.G., 2012. Spectral theory and analytic geometry over non-Archimedean fields (No. 33). American Mathematical Soc..

Comment: Dear Alex Youcis, thank you for the answer and sorry for the late reply. I'll try to understand the notion of a normal rigid space. On a more pedantic note, in the second example, is the prime p assumed to be different from 2?

Comment: @sriram Yes, you should globally assume that for me $p>2$ :)